# How can I browse OSX shared resources from Ubuntu server?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, network-shares

What I want is to check what resources are shared on OSX from my Ubuntu server, then I can mount particular resource using mount.cifs. From Windows 7 I can browse and see what resources are available (root level shares), however I'm not sure how to do that from headless Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `smbclient -L server` to list shares on a particular SMB server.

Comment: It's no SMB server, it's Mac OS.

Comment: @Pablo: SMB is a *protocol* (a derivative of CIFS), not an operating system. When you browse the shares from Windows, you are connecting using SMB.

Comment: this will `only` work if on OS X file sharing -> `Share files and folders using SMB (Windows)` is turned ON. As I am not sharing NTFS based partitions, this option is useless. Is there way to list resources based on AFP protocol?

Comment: @Pablo, the option **is not related to NTFS at all.** You can share *any* filesystem over *any* protocol. Second, you *yourself* said that you intend to use `mount.cifs`, which uses SMB and not AFP.